# How do I fix Project type launch profiles in VS 2017 asp.net core web applications?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I migrated a core web application from VS 2015 to VS 2017, and now when I try to run it with a launch profile of type "Project" it fails to attach the javascript debugger and VS gives an error message that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is my launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    ...
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      ...
    },
    "MyProject": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5432",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Testing"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in Visual Studio 2017. You can fix it by manually changing the "launchUrl" property of your Project type profile to "applicationUrl" instead.

```
"MyProject": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5432",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Testing"
  }
}
```